# Creating an IProcess that isn't a wrapper for a system process

Tags: eclipse, language-agnostic, eclipse-plugin

In the article (and examples) [How to write an Eclipse Debugger](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html) the implementation of ILaunch creates a new IDebugTarget (only in debug mode, not in run mode). While doing so it always creates a new system process, and wraps it into an IProcess (most likely this implementation of IProcess, org.eclipse.debug.core.model.RuntimeProcess). It attaches the IProcess to the IDebugTarget.

My question is, does a debug target, for any language, NOT Java, necessarilyneed a system process? I have a langauge which doesn't execute or debug from a one-off system command, it is all based on a socket. Do I need to implement a new IProcess for this? Is that even possible/feasible, since IProcess appears to be a system process wrapper. Does Eclipse force the model of having a new system process spawn from eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, it is possible and also a good idea. The entire IProcess interface could very well be a server connection, as many IDEs either spawn a process or open a connection to a server (like an interactive interpreter, or a full blown app server). Of course there is no common implementation for a server based IProcess, but spawning a process on a local is a very easy thing to have a concrete class provided for by Eclipse, hence when RuntimeProcess is available.

Also, it even says (not in the article, but the same author gave a presentation in which he covers spawning versus connecting to a server. Specifically he says to implement your own IProcess if you are not simply spawning.